# Как написать в cmd через qt?

Tags: qt

Ребята, добрый день.

Хочу сделать, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку "ок" открывался cmd и выполняла вот эти команды:

```
cd / ,d:  ,cd D:\out_file,  node out_file
```

Я нашёл ответ. Вдруг кому-то понадобится

```
QProcess process(this);
process.start("cmd");
if (process.waitForReadyRead()) process.waitForReadyRead();
ui->plainTextEdit->appendPlainText(process.readAll());
```

Comment: Что за ошибка?

Comment: Почему везде `/c`?

Answer (score 1):

Функция `system("здесь ваша команда");`

Comment: QProcess process(this);

    process.start("cmd");
    if (process.waitForReadyRead()) process.waitForReadyRead();
    ui->plainTextEdit->appendPlainText(process.readAll());